# Adding Facebook Javascript SDK into my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to use the Facebook Javascript SDK, and right now I am just pasting this code into my erb template that has the like button:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

However, in the Facebook developer docs, it is said that something like this is prefered direct right after the body open tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel file for x-domain comms
      status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

So, my question is:

-> Where should I place this code? In my layout or in a Javascript file that using jQuery does all this logic?

Comment: Did you figure out where to put this?

Answer (score 0):

put the code into bottom of your main templates eg application.html.erb or base.html.erb[if your have base controller that inherited from application controlller]